# Get all values input checkbox selected with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 inputs checkbox, select 3 and when you want to see the number selected with this function I get the number 3 correctly

```
$('.pf-fdc-setting .class-users .class-role input:checked').length(); // 3
```

but if I want to get the 3 values, just send me 1 single value with this function

```
$('.pf-fdc-setting .class-users .class-role input:checked').val(); // one-value
```

How can I get the 3 values selected?

Comment: Why don't you read it individually as it holds different classes. There's no need to looping though

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the selected items

```
let values = [];
$('.pf-fdc-setting .class-users .class-role input:checked').each(function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Do It:

```
$('.pf-fdc-setting .class-users .class-role input:checked').each( function( index, element ){
   console.log( $( this ).val() );
});
```